# How do I prevent owasp/modsecurity Docker container from overwriting my nginx.conf

Tags: docker, nginx, mod-security

I am attempting to update my reg nginx server (docker container) to nginx w/ mod security (docker container).  The Nginx configs / Certs / Everything was working with plain Nginx.

I am attempting to use https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/modsecurity# specificily `owasp/modsecurity:nginx-alpine`

However, every time I run the container my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and /etc/nginx/conf.d/ keep getting completely overwritten.

On the one hand, i get that they are writing the config to make use of mod security
but I am lost at how they expect an enduser to customize the config or add lets-encrypt keys if they overwrite everything.

Here is my current setup:

```
docker run \
  --name ms-nginx \
  -d --restart=always \
  -p 80:80 \
  -p 443:443 \
  -v /opt/containers/nginx/modsecurity.d:/etc/modsecurity.d \
  -v /opt/containers/nginx/config:/etc/nginx \
  -v /opt/containers/nginx/www:/var/www:ro \
  -v /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt:ro \
  -v /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/dhparam-2048.pem:ro \
  owasp/modsecurity:nginx-alpine
```

Am I doing it wrong? should it be turtles all the way down and I point my main nginx to another Nginx w/ mod security which points to a specific web service?  This seems like it should be easy and I am just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Documentation (https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/modsecurity):

> What happens if I want to make changes in a different file, like
> `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`? You mount your local file, e.g.
> `nginx/default.conf` as the new template:
> `/etc/nginx/templates/conf.d/default.conf.template`. You can do this
> similarly with other files. Files in the templates directory will be
> copied and subdirectories will be preserved.